# Highlight selected text is not working properly in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a text Highlight feature in react app. It is not working for few cases that I have mentioned bellow.

**Sentence:**

> A quick fox jumps over a lazy dog

Not working for the following cases.

Let's assume I have highlighted the text *'**quick fox jumps**'*,

- from here if i try to Highlight by selecting the word ***'fox'***, in that case it is appending mark tag inside mark tag (
  `<mark>quick <mark>fox</mark> jumps</mark>`). it should be remain as is `<mark>quick fox jumps</mark>`
- if try select form text *'**jumps over**'*, I am getting the following error
- also how can we remove the Highlighted text

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.
```

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedHtml, setSelectedHtml] = useState([]);
  const selectedRef = useRef(null);
  const handleSelection = () => {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    parent = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;

    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const selectedText = range.toString();
      console.log(selectedText, "selected text");
      if (selectedText) {
        const clonedRange = range.cloneRange();
        const mark = document.createElement("mark");
        range.surroundContents(mark);
        setSelectedHtml((prev) => [...prev, PerformanceMark.outerHTML]);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p onMouseUp={handleSelection} ref={selectedRef}>
        A quick fox jumps over a lazy dog.
      </p>
      <div>Selected HTML: {selectedHtml}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is [Codepen demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hilight-text-v37vjw?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your initial issue, you will need to create a function that checks for the conditions(the nested mark tags and partially selected non-Text nodes) and modify the selection accordingly. Below is the function `checkAndModifySelection` which I created to modify the range if the start or end containers are within a `mark` tag. This will prevent nested mark tags and errors caused by partially selected non-Text nodes.

```js
const checkAndModifySelection = (range) => {
    const startContainer = range.startContainer;
    const endContainer = range.endContainer;

    if (startContainer.parentElement.tagName === "MARK") {
      range.setStart(startContainer.parentElement, 0);
    }

    if (endContainer.parentElement.tagName === "MARK") {
      range.setEnd(endContainer.parentElement, 1);
    }
  };
```

##### How to remove the highlighted text?

There can be many ways to achieve this. I'll give you the example of achieving this using `button`. You can extend as per your requirement. This function(which gets triggered on button click) iterates through all the `<mark>` elements within the `selectedRef's` current element and removes them while preserving the original text. It also resets the `selectedHtml` state.

```js
const removeHighlights = () => {
  const markElements = selectedRef.current.getElementsByTagName("mark");
  while (markElements.length > 0) {
    const markElement = markElements[0];
    const parentElement = markElement.parentElement;
    while (markElement.firstChild) {
      parentElement.insertBefore(markElement.firstChild, markElement);
    }
    parentElement.removeChild(markElement);
  }
  setSelectedHtml([]);
};
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/weathered-firefly-t9v7hf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A66%2C13)***

**Suggestion:**

To achieve the requirement more cleanly and for handling complex scenarios, you may want to consider using a library like *[react-highlight-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight-words)* to handle text highlighting more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. for the first case, it is still getting mark tag inside mark tag. I am looking to remove specific highlight selections instead of all.